# Fire back two success in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to separate the result after requesting in ajax

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userno" id='stud_id' readonly > 
<input type="text"name="studentname" id='studentname' readonly >
<input type='submit' name='stud' onclick='showstudent_info()'>

function showstudent_info(){    
var  studid = $('#studid').val();
  console.log(studid);
    if(studid){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'parentinfo.php',
            data: 'studid='+studid,
            success:function(html){
                var infoid = html
                $('#stud_id').val(info);
                var studname = html
                $('#studentname').val(studname);
            }
        }); 
    }
  }
```

this is my parentinfo.php page

```
parentinfo.php
$stud_id = $_POST['studid'];
$qry = "Select studtbl.stud_id,concat(studtbl.fname,' ', 
substring(studtbl.mname, 1,1),'. ',studtbl.lname) as Name from studtbl where 
stud_id = $stud_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    extract($row);
    $info = $row['stud_id'];
    $studname = $row['Name'];
}
echo $info;
echo $studname;
```

my problem is the value of infoid and studname is joined e.g(1Albert Einstein)

Comment: Return a json array in your php. Plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: Can you edit your question and input the result data from parentinfo.php ?

Comment: I already edited it sir @jerome

Answer (score 2):

Send it as JSON so you can break it up server side to make it readable as a javascript object client side instead of parsing a string sent from server

In php would be something like:

```
$outputArray = array(
   'id'=> $idVariable,
   'name'=> $nameVariable
);

echo json_encode($outputArray);
```

Then in js add `dataType:'json'` to the ajax options and success callback would be something like:

```
success:function(responseObject){
     var infoid = responseObject.id;
     $('#stud_id').val(infoid );
     var studname = responseObject.name;
     $('#studentname').val(studname);
}
```